# How can we use SendGrid for Outbound Email?

Tags: cme, 2013-sp1, outbound-email

We are planning to use SendGrid for all email functionalities for all of the environments (DEV/TEST/UAT/PROD).

Can anybody let me know how can I enable the same? As Outbound email saves emails into a directory, which is being used as an input for any SMTP; I am not sure if we can use SendGrid for this. Please guide.

Also let me know how can we provide bounce email settings.

If I am not wrong, these bounce emails are used to track the successful outbound email deliveries? Please confirm.

TRIDION 2013 SP1, Windows Azure Cloud

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is really an SDL Tridion question, you're best off reading the send grid API so see if you can hook this up to the email directory:

https://sendgrid.com/docs/API_Reference/index.html

I suspect you'll need to write something to take the files and push them to Send Grid.

**Note**: Advice given without looking at their API :)